# How many instruction counters are required for a multithreaded program?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I am guessing that you need at least one instruction counter for each thread but I am not really sure.

Comment: That might very much depend on various details, for example whether your underlying hardware is able to run multiple threads in parallel or not.

Comment: At minimum, one program-counter register.  You can run a multi-threaded program on a single-core CPU, just context-switching and saving task state (including program counter) in memory.